# How to generate sklearn classification report for multiclass multioutput data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the below code to calculate F1 score for my dataset

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

m = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit(y_test_true_f)

print("F1-score is : {:.1%}".format(f1_score(m.transform(y_test_true_f),
         m.transform(y_pred_f),
         average='macro')))
```

and classification report

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(m.transform(y_test_true_f), m.transform(y_pred_f)))
```

but the output of the classification report does not show the label names

```
                 precision  recall   f1-score   support

           0       0.88      1.00      0.94        15
           1       1.00      0.95      0.98        22
           2       0.82      0.74      0.78        19
           3       0.90      0.85      0.88        33
           4       0.68      0.87      0.76        15
           5       0.94      0.98      0.96        46
           6       0.83      0.94      0.88        16
           7       0.33      0.86      0.48         7
           8       0.95      0.90      0.92        20
           9       0.67      1.00      0.80        10
          10       0.91      0.83      0.87        12
          11       0.29      0.33      0.31         6
          12       0.25      0.40      0.31         5
          13       0.00      0.00      0.00         3
          14       0.88      1.00      0.93         7
          15       0.50      0.75      0.60         8
          16       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
          17       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
          18       0.80      1.00      0.89         8
          19       0.89      1.00      0.94        17
          20       0.88      1.00      0.94        15
          21       0.86      0.80      0.83        15
          22       0.71      0.79      0.75        19
          23       0.65      1.00      0.79        11
          24       0.74      0.82      0.78        17
          25       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
          26       0.75      0.86      0.80        14
```

How shall I update my code to see the label names instead of numbers 0,1,2,3.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to output there are 27 classes in the dataset if am not wrong. For getting the classes name/label you need to use attribute of `MultiLabelBinarizer` to get the mapping of `class` and `0,1,2,3,...` because it transform label into `1,2,3,...` numeric type

Attribute is [`.classes_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#:%7E:text=CSR%20sparse%20format.-,Attributes,-classes_ndarray%20of), you could add this as an parameter in your [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html?highlight=classification_report#:%7E:text=in%20the%20report.-,target_names,-list%20of%20str) as follows:

```py
print(classification_report(m.transform(y_test_true_f), m.transform(y_pred_f)),target_names=m.classes_)
```

I hope this could give you classes label.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I used to thought when they map to numeric where we can find the mapping for label and numeric group. After going through documentation I found most **properties, attributes and mapping** can be obtained through object's attributes for almost all models.

Answer (score 1):

Specify them as `target_names` when calling `classification_report`.

From their [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html):

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
>>> y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
>>> target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
>>> print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```